# Dynamically add methods to a python class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to create a decent number of classes with attributes that all follow the same pattern. I want to create a succinct way to do this with the goal of using a script to lay out all the classes so I can avoid repetitive work.

```
add_get_for(class_type, property):
  class_type[property] = lambda self: self._attributes[property]

class A:
  def __init__(self, input_object):
     self._attributes = process(input_object)
  
add_get_for(A, 'attrib1')
add_get_for(A, 'attrib2')
```

The `add_get_for` method is failing because of item assignment on the class. I can't figure out a way to assign the lambda function without knowing the name of the method in advance which is pointless for my goal.

Comment: f = lambda: …. ;
setattr(class_type, property, f) ??

Comment: I am not convinced it’s a dupe as decorators may not be what OP wants to use.

Comment: A method is just a function object that is an attribute of a class object. You can add an attribute to any object (if it is allowed) by using `setattr(obj, name, value)` where `value` is your function, and `name` is the name of the attribute as a `str`

Comment: That being said, it looks like you are overcomplicating things, particularly, what is `_attributes`? is it a `dict`? Why have a `dict` that has attributes, that you then write getters for? I suspect there is a much cleaner way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) with a lambda and a f-string:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, input_object):
     self._attributes = process(input_object)

def process(input_object):
  return input_object

def add_get_for(class_type, property):
  setattr(class_type, f'get_{property}', lambda self: self._attributes[property])

add_get_for(A, 'attrib1')
add_get_for(A, 'attrib2')
obj = A({'attrib1': 'value1', 'attrib2': 'value2'})
print(obj.get_attrib1())  # type: ignore so static type checkers don't complain
print(obj.get_attrib2())  # type: ignore so static type checkers don't complain
```

**Output:**

```
value1
value2
```